# Load reCAPTCHA dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, recaptcha

There are several ways to load reCAPTCHA using javascript such as below:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Loading captcha with JavaScript</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var captchaContainer = null;
    var loadCaptcha = function() {
      captchaContainer = grecaptcha.render('captcha_container', {
        'sitekey' : 'Your sitekey',
        'callback' : function(response) {
          console.log(response);
        }
      });
    };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="captcha_container"></div>
      <input type="button" id="MYBTN" value="MYBTN">
      <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=loadCaptcha&render=explicit" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This code load captcha on pageload. I want load reCAPTCHA just when clicked on "MYBTN". So the code changes into:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Loading captcha with JavaScript</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
$('#MYBTN').on('click',function(){
    var captchaContainer = null;
    var loadCaptcha = function() {
      captchaContainer = grecaptcha.render('captcha_container', {
        'sitekey' : 'Your sitekey',
        'callback' : function(response) {
          console.log(response);
        }
      });
    };
 });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="captcha_container"></div>
      <input type="button" id="MYBTN" value="MYBTN">
      <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=loadCaptcha&render=explicit" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But this code didn't work when I click on "MYBTN" and reCAPTCHA not load.

Answer (score 14):

You just need to call loadCaptcha()

```js
$('#MYBTN').on('click',function(){
    var captchaContainer = null;
    var loadCaptcha = function() {
      captchaContainer = grecaptcha.render('captcha_container', {
        'sitekey' : 'Your sitekey',
        'callback' : function(response) {
          console.log(response);
        }
      });
    };
    loadCaptcha(); // THIS LINE WAS MISSING
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
      <div id="captcha_container"></div>
      <input type="button" id="MYBTN" value="MYBTN">
      <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=loadCaptcha&render=explicit"></script>
```

Comment: because you mixed the 2 versions that are in your question. You said you have a working version for onload, and asked for a version which loads only onclick. The code you have on your website now loads onload. You need change the full js part to what's in my answer (the onclick thing...)

Answer (score 9):

**Simple situation**

**Html**

```
<input type="button" id="MYBTN" value="create captcha"> 
<div id="captcha_container"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var testSitekey = '6LeLzA4UAAAAANNRnB8kePzikGgmZ53aWQiruo7O';

$('#MYBTN').click(function() {
  $('body').append($('<div id="captcha_container" class="google-cpatcha"></div>'));
  setTimeout(function() {
    grecaptcha.render('captcha_container', {
      'sitekey': testSitekey
    });
  }, 1000);
});
```

[**Online demo (jsfiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/554qx557/)

Comment: Thanks this was useful!

Answer (score 6):

You just mentioned onload in your embedded script. Either you just remove onload from your embedded script or just keep your code outside of the onclick event in the function name loadCaptcha.

**1. First Solution:**

```
$('#MYBTN').on('click',function(){
    var captchaContainer = null;
    var loadCaptcha = function() {
      captchaContainer = grecaptcha.render('captcha_container', {
        'sitekey' : 'Your sitekey',
        'callback' : function(response) {
          console.log(response);
        }
      });
    }
 });

<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit"></script>
```

**2. Second Solution**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var captchaContainer = null;
    var loadCaptcha = function() {
      captchaContainer = grecaptcha.render('captcha_container', {
        'sitekey' : 'Your sitekey',
        'callback' : function(response) {
          console.log(response);
        }
      });
    };
 </script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=loadCaptcha&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

In first Solution your code will work when you click your button. Even you don't have to put then in loadCaptcha function you can directly call grecaptcha.render.

But when you mention onload in your script tag then it will not work according to your click then it will find the callback function you mentioned in the script. And as you wrote the loadCaptcha in onload of script and you wrote this function inside the onClick event. When the script tag executed, the code tried to find the loadCaptcha function which was not initialised till the script tag executed (as it would initialise on click event), So your script was not working.

Answer (score 3):

**JS**

```
// Loading captcha with JavaScript on button click
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#MYBTN').on('click',function() {
        $.getScript( "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=__YOUR_KEY__" )
        .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
            if(typeof grecaptcha !== "undefined") {
                grecaptcha.ready(function () {
                    grecaptcha.execute('__YOUR_KEY__', {
                        action: 'homepage'
                    })
                    .then(function (token) {
                        var recaptchaResponse = document.getElementById('captcha_container');
                        recaptchaResponse.value = token;
                    });

                    // Your other code here
                    // You can control captcha badge here
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
// Required HTML:
<body>
    <input type="button" id="MYBTN" value="MYBTN">
    <div id="captcha_container"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: The problem of this approach is that on every click on that button will insert the recaptcha JS again and challenge the customer. So, if for some reason the user clicks 10 times in that button, the page would freeze.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for comment, Ricardo

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented the captcha to be loaded only after one of the required fields of my form was focus. I also implemented a check variable to see if the captcha's dependencies were inserted before.

Here is is:

```js
jQuery('#MyRequiredInputId').focus(function () {
                if(typeof loadedRecaptcha != 'undefined'){
                    return;
                }
                jQuery.getScript("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=___YOURKEY__")
                    .done(function (script, textStatus) {
                        if (typeof grecaptcha !== "undefined") {
                            grecaptcha.ready(function () {
                            var siteKey = '___YOURKEY___';
                                jQuery('body').append(jQuery('<div id="captcha_container" class="google-cpatcha"></div>'));
                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    grecaptcha.render('captcha_container', {
                                        'sitekey': siteKey
                                    });
                                }, 1000);
                            });
                        }
                        loadedRecaptcha = true;
                    });
        });
```

Note that in my case, I have a `<div id= "captcha_container"></div>` where I want to display my captcha.

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue today when I discovered that there are about 21 requests for Google Recaptcha even without open the login modal, this is indeed too much ):

After trying this method:

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 btm10">
     <div id="captcha_container"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
<script>
var Sitekey = '<?php echo config('google_key') ?>';

$('#loginbtn').click(function() {
  $('body').append($('<div id="captcha_container" class="google-cpatcha"></div>'));
  setTimeout(function() {
    grecaptcha.render('captcha_container', {
      'sitekey': Sitekey
    });
  }, 1000);
});
</script>
```

finally, I get the results I want, now the recaptcha only loads when the login modal opens (based onClick function).

**Unfortunately,** I found that the main Google Recaptcha script still loads in console even while using the delay method mentioned above because the main script is declared on the page head:

`<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>`

[image: recaptcha script loads in console]

So, I removed it from the `page head` then combined some lines of codes together to get it to work and only loads when the modal opens as follow:

Final code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 btm10">
     <div id="captcha_container"></div>
   </div> //Wherever you want the reCaptcha to appear
</div>

<script>
//Add to the header or the footer it doesn't matter

var Sitekey = '<?php echo config('google_key') ?>';

$('#loginbtn').click(function() {
  $.getScript("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js") //The trick is here.
  $('body').append($('<div id="captcha_container" class="google-cpatcha"></div>'));
  setTimeout(function() {
    grecaptcha.render('captcha_container', {
      'sitekey': Sitekey
    });
  }, 1000);
});
</script>
```

You can view it in action here:
https://youtu.be/dAZOSMR8iI8

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Tell Google you want to render the recaptcha explicitly (when you are ready). https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit
After the api script has run grecaptcha is available globally.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head> </head>
      <body>
        <div id="whereIWantRecaptcha"></div>
        <button id="myButton">show Recaptcha</button>
        <script
          src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit"
          async
          defer
        ></script>
        
        <script>
          var button = document.querySelector('#myButton');
          button.addEventListener('click', function(){
            grecaptcha.render('whereIWantRecaptcha', {
              'sitekey' : '6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI'
            });
          });
        </script>
        
      </body>
    </html>
```